# Setting UIImage as background of a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiimage

Whats wrong with the following piece of code:

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 33, 33);
    button.frame = frame;
    button.tag = 1001;
    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc]init]autorelease];
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [image release];
    [button release];
```

If this is wrong where does it need correction and why?

Comment: **if** it is wrong? Have you tried it? you should know if it is working or not.

Comment: It would be much easier to do this in IB. Create a button, set the type to custom, and then set the image. Is there a reason you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: Its working for me. But I was told that  `UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc]init]autorelease];
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];`  is a wrong approach.

Comment: @Osiris  My requirement was to do it programmatically

Comment: @XaviValero View The dbrajkovic and Looyao's Answer.
And You should also Review Your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see several problems:

1. You sent autorelease to image, then manually released it.
2. You released button, but you didn't add it as a subview to anything. So basically, you did all that for nothing.
3. You instantiate UIImage, then you do instantiate it again. in the next line: Instead just do:
   `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];`
   and delete `UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc]init]autorelease];` and `[image release];` statement.

Comment: You should also look at looyao's answer below!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 33, 33);;
button.tag = 1001;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
if (image == nil) {
    NSLog(@"can't find icon.png");
} else {
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
//add button to the parent's view
```

Comment: Good call. I missed the first line! One more thing. get rid of the .png. `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];`  That way,  it will automatically load icon@2x (if you added it to your project) for the RetinaDisplay

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure `image` is not `nil`?